# What's a French equivalent for the English expression “choked up”?

Tags: traduction, anglais

The English expression *choked up* means that one becomes speechless, as from the effect of emotion or stress; often, it suggests that one cries, too.  For example:

> I got choked up when I heard about his pet dying.

Is there a similar expression in French to express this phenomenon?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

« Laisser sans voix ». Par exemple : « apprendre la mort de son animal de compagnie m'a laissé sans voix. »

Edit : après la remarque de Benjol sur le fait qu'il manque l'idée d'être au bord des larmes, « la gorge nouée » me semble meilleur comme traduction.

Comment: Je suis pasfrancophone, mais pour moi 'laisser sans voix' parle plutôt d'un choc qu'un bord de larmes.

Comment: @Benjol, tu as raison, je propose donc « la gorge nouée ».

Comment: @Benjol "m'a laissé sans voix" s'applique à ce contexte également. L'interlocuteur comprend que le choc est émotionnel. "la gorge nouée" peut s'employer aussi, mais n'évoque pas exactement le même chose : il y a l'idée de tristesse, mais l'idée de choc disparaît. A la limite, il y a un décalage temporel entre les deux. D'abord le choc qui "laisse sans voix", puis "la gorge nouée".

Answer (score 14):

In theory, [pantois](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pantois) is the word, but I've never heard anyone actually use it.

> Quand j'ai appris qu'il était mort, ça m'a laissé pantois.

ou

> Quand j'ai appris qu'il était mort, j'en suis resté pantois.

More commonly, you'll hear *J'en suis resté sans voix*, or maybe *J'en suis resté bouche bée*, *J'en étais muet de tristesse*, *Je suis tombé sur le cul* (very informal). See also the synonyms of *pantois* on its page; most are in use, in particular *soufflé*, *sidéré*, *estomaqué*.

**EDIT**: je viens d'encore en trouver un qui à mon avis convient vraiment mieux: *bouleversé*:

> J'ai été bouleversé d'apprendre la mort de Jules.

Comment: "Bouleversé" est tout à fait approprié car il donne l'idée de choc comme l'idée de détresse. Or on parle bien des deux à la fois ici. C'est mieux que "pantois" qui, à mon oreille de français, sonne comme une stupéfaction, mais dépourvue de tristesse... et qui est plus littéraire, aussi.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to stay close to the literal English meaning, you can use "**[suffoqué](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/suffoquer)**".

It has the same literal meaning of loosing one's breath and it also conveys the same emotional meaning as *to choke up*.

**Edit**
Actually, I just realised that Joubarc's answer is also close to the literal sense of choke up because this is the original meaning of **pantois** in Ancient French (which is still alive in the English verb *to pant* from OFr *pantoisier*, precisely).  In French you also have "pantelant".

Another good one is "en avoir le souffle coupé":

> ça m'a coupé le souffle!!!

or

> j'en ai eu le soufle coupé

Passing from the lungs to the stomach, you can say:

> j'en suis resté estomaqué

A whole bunch of synonyms still, all of which inspired by unpleasant physical consequences provoked by the surprise:

- abasourdi => dumbfound;
- époustouflé => choked up;
- étonné => muted
- médusé => from the Greek [Medusa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medusa) who could turn you to stone if you crossed her gaze;
- pétrifié => petrified, same idea;
- stupéfait stupéfié => awe-inspired;
- ebaubis => made to stammer;

Answer (score 5):

"Elle est resté **bouche bée**"

The first word means **mouth**, but combined with "bée" — the French definition is:

> 1. la bouche ouverte, par admiration ou stupeur.

This would totally fit for hearing about your friend's pet dying.

Comment: To translate your example: "J'ai resté bouche-bée quand il m'as informé de son animal mourant."

Comment: "Je suis resté bouche bée lorsqu'il m'a parlé de son animal mourant" est plus correct.

Answer (score 4):

« J'étais retourné », ou « j'étais complètement retourné », traduit il me semble assez bien la combinaison de l'émotion avec les effets de stress, de silence, de tristesse et de larmes.

Answer (score 3):

*J'en suis resté coi* n'a pas été encore proposé et je l'aime bien. Par contre il n'est vraiment plus d'usage courant.

Comment: Actually [also present in English](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=coy&searchmode=term) in the original sense of "voiceless".

Answer (score 2):

*Stupéfait* et *interdit* n'ont pas encore été proposés, alors je les rajoute pour la complétude de la liste…